# Which book better for Fourier analysis?

Tags: fourier-transform

Which book better for Fourier analysis starting from very basic term i have no any knowledge about Fourier analysis suggest me book please

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Paul Nahin has written a good general guide, which is textbook level imo. A free pdf is available if you search " dr euler's fabulous formula pdf" My tablet won't copy the link, apologies

Answer (score 1):

An Introduction to Fourier Analysis and Generalised Functions by Lighthill is a good one, despite being a bit mathematical.

The Fourier Transform and its Applications- course notes by Prof. Brad Osgood is very good starting from Fourier series. Very detailed and explains the ideas in a clear and precise way stressing physical insights. This might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Fourier Analysis and Its Applications](http://bookstore.ams.org/amstext-4) by Folland is good. It's mathematically correct, but not too heavy according to my measures.